# DataFrame Column Subset by Reference

Tags: julia, pass-by-reference, dataframes.jl

I have a DataFrame `x` with two UInt32 columns. The following function searches for a value from the first column in a subset of the second column:

```
findfirst(==(x[y, 1]), x[1:(y - 1), 2])
```

`y` is a scalar, e.g. 10. If I understand https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/indexing correctly, `x[1:(y - 1), 2])` copies the region of the DataFrame. How can I have `findfirst` search that part of `x` in place, i.e. by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@view`:

```
findfirst(==(x[y, 1]), @view x[1:(y - 1), 2])
```

#### Explanation

Suppose you have `df = DataFrame(rand(1:99,5,2), :auto);` than indexing does copying (as in your question) while `@view` yields a reference to the data:

```
julia> df[1:3, 2]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 62
 88
 11

julia> @view df[1:3, 2]
3-element view(::Vector{Int64}, 1:3) with eltype Int64:
 62
 88
 11
```

Also note that if you want a reference to the entire column you can do `df[!, 2]`. Look at the two codes below (one gives the reference while the other copies the data and hence the number of allocated bytes).

```
julia> @allocated df[!, 2]
0

julia> @allocated df[:, 2]
96
```